# Rip CD to FLAC on Mavericks

Tags: macos, audio, flac

I have a large collection of Audio CDs I would like to convert to audio files. My requirements are:

- [FLAC](https://xiph.org/flac/) and MP3 support: I would like to keep a lossless version of the CDs in original quality.
- CDDB / MusicBrainz connectivity: I would like to have the track and album filenames downloaded from the net, rather than type them manually.
- OSX Mavericks compatibility
- Reasonable GUI

Is there a good application for that, preferably using an open-source one?

Comment: Do you want to rip your Audio CDs *into* FLAC files, do you just want to playback FLAC files or do you have FLAC files you want to convert into something playable by iTunes

Comment: I would like to convert my Audio CDs to FLAC files on the mac Hard drive, and I don't want iTunes to be involved. Edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[X Lossless Decoder](http://tmkk.undo.jp/xld/index_e.html), [Max](http://sbooth.org/Max/). Both open source and for mac.

Comment: You may also check out [FFMPEG](http://www.ffmpeg.org), a command line tool for converting nearly every audio and video file. Cheers!

Comment: xld works fine, thanks. Max is a little outdated (last updated in 2009).

Comment: Yes, you're right. :)

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't do that ...

Comment: Max still working well here, X Lossless Decoder looks a bit command-line for my liking

Comment: Another very good command-line alternative is [cdparanoia](https://www.xiph.org/paranoia/), available in most any open-source package manager such as pkgsrc, homebrew, etc.